# App crashing while using breakpoints in Xcode

Tags: xcode, debugging, breakpoints

I am using Xcode 11.5. My all apps crashing while I'm using the breakpoint debugger. It's working fine without breakpoints. I'm not able to debug any app.

I am sharing a screenshot of the crash which Xcode is giving.
Thank you.
[image]

Comment: What breakpoints do you have set?  (Is it really a crash?  What happens if you click the "continue" button?)

Comment: I set the breakpoint in viewDidLoad(). On click on the continue button then it's running but I'm not able to debug my app.

Comment: Do you have the menu item turned on for Debug->Debug Workflow->Always Show Disassembly?

Comment: Thank you @PhillipMills It's working when it turned off.